# Kraus representation of linear maps

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-information

I wish to prove the following theorem:

Theorem: For every linear map $\Phi\in T(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ there exist sets of operators $\{A_r: r\in\Sigma\}$ and $\{B_r: r\in\Sigma\}$, with $A_r:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ and $B_r:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\Phi(X)=\sum_r A_r X B_r^*,~~~~~~\forall X\in L(\mathcal{X}),
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space, $L(\mathcal{X})$ is the set of linear operators from $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{X}$ and $T(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ is the set of all linear maps from $L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{Y})$.

This is what I have so far as proof:

Let $\{E_{kl}\}$ and $\{E_{mn}\}$ be the standard bases for $L(\mathcal{X})$ and $L(\mathcal{Y})$ respectively. Expanding $X$ in the operator basis for $L(\mathcal{X})$ and using linearity of $\Phi$ we have 
\begin{equation}
\Phi(X)=\sum_{kl}X_{kl}~\Phi(E_{kl}).
\end{equation}
The above implies that 
\begin{equation}
\Phi(X)=\sum_{kl,mn}X_{kl}~\langle m |\Phi(E_{kl})|n\rangle |m\rangle\langle n|\\
=\sum_{kl,mn}\langle m |\Phi(E_{kl})|n\rangle |m\rangle\langle k|~X~|l\rangle\langle n|.
\end{equation}
This implies that 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:vecphi(X)}
vec\Big(\Phi(X)\Big)=\sum_{kl,mn}\langle m |\Phi(E_{kl})|n\rangle~vec\Big( |m\rangle\langle k|~X~|l\rangle\langle n|\Big)\notag\\
=\sum_{kl,mn}\langle m |\Phi(E_{kl})|n\rangle |m\rangle\langle  k|\otimes|n\rangle\langle l|~vec\big(X\big)\notag\\
=\Phi\Big(vec\big(X\big)\Big).
\end{equation}
The last equality follows from the linearity of vec and $\Phi$.
Thus, 
\begin{equation}
\Phi=\sum_{kl, mn}\phi_{mk,nl}~|m\rangle\langle   k|\otimes|n\rangle\langle   l|,
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
\phi_{mk,nl}=\langle m |\Phi(E_{kl})|n\rangle.
\end{equation}

Note that the above equation can also be expressed as
\begin{equation}
\Phi=\sum_{kl, mn}\phi_{mk, nl}~|mn \rangle\langle kl|\notag\\
=\sum_{kl, mn}\phi_{mk, nl}~vec\Big(E_{mn}\Big)vec\Big(E_{kl}\Big)^*,
\end{equation}

As $\Phi\in T(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$, it admits a singular value decomposition, namely sets of vectors $\{x_1,x_2,...x_r\}\subset\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{X}$ and $\{y_1,y_2,...y_r\}\subset\mathcal{Y}\otimes\mathcal{Y}$ along with a set of positive reals $\{s_1, s_2,...s_r\}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\Phi=\sum_rs_ry_rx_r^*.
\end{equation}
The last two equations together imply
\begin{equation}
\phi_{mk,nl}=\sum_r s_r vec\Big(E_{mn}\Big)^*y_rx_r^*vec\Big(E_{kl}\Big)\notag\\
=\sum_r s_r ~a_{mn}^r ~b_{kl}^{r*}, 
\end{equation}
where $a_{mn}^r=vec\Big(E_{mn}\Big)^*y_r$ and $b_{kl}^{r*}=x_r^*~vec\Big(E_{kl}\Big)$. Recalling the second equation from the top for $\Phi(X)$  and using the expression for $\phi_{mknl}$ we have
\begin{equation}
\Phi(X)=\sum_{kl,mn}\phi_{mk, nl} |m\rangle\langle k|~X~|l\rangle\langle n|\\
=\sum_r s_r \sum_{kl,mn} ~a_{mn}^r ~b_{kl}^{r*} |m\rangle\langle k|~X~|l\rangle\langle n|.
\end{equation}

Now, if one could interchange the indices $n$ and $k$ one would be through as then the sum of $m,k$ would give an operator that would multiply $X$ from the left and summing over $l,n$ would give an operator that would multiply $X$ from the right. However, that is certainly not obvious.

I know an alternative proof that uses the Choi-Jamilkowski isomorphism. However, I'm not sure if this proof can be completed or if it is wrong.

Any comment or reference would be of great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your method of proof will not work. First of all, your Theorem as stated is incorrect, since your operators $A_r$ and $B_r$ are not on the correct spaces. The correctly stated theorem is:

**Theorem**: For every linear map $\Phi\in \operatorname{T}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ there exist collections of operators $\{A_r: r\in\Sigma\}\subset\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ and $\{B_r: r\in\Sigma\}\subset\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ such that 
$$
\Phi(X)=\sum_r A_r X B_r^*,~~~~~~\forall X\in L(\mathcal{X}).
$$

That is, each $A_r$ and $B_r$ is a linear operator from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$ (not from $\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X})$ to $\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$, as your theorem statement indicates).

It is helpful to introduce the following notation to be able to discriminate between the mapping and its matrix representation (both of which you call $\Phi$ in your question). 
The *natural representation* of a linear mapping $\Phi\in\operatorname{T}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ is the operator $K(\Phi)\in\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}\otimes\mathcal{Y})$ defined as
$$
K(\Phi)x\otimes y = \operatorname{vec}(\Phi(xy^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathsf{T}}))
$$
for all vectors $x,y\in\mathcal{X}$ (or analgously as $K(\Phi)\operatorname{vec}(X)=\operatorname{vec}(\Phi(X))$ for all operators $X\in\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X})$).

The "matrix entries" of the natural representation $K(\Phi)$ are now what you call $\phi_{mk,nl}$. Namely, the values $\phi_{mk,nl}$ satisfy
$$
K(\Phi)(\operatorname{vec}(E_{k,l})) = \sum_{m,n}\phi_{mk,nl}\operatorname{vec}(E_{m,n}).
$$
Following your attempted proof, we can find a singular value decomposition of $K(\Phi)$ by choosing operators $A_r\in\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X})$ and $B_r\in\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{Y})$ such that
$$
K(\Phi) = \sum_r \operatorname{vec}(B_r)\operatorname{vec}(A_r)^* \tag{$1$}
$$
(where we can absorb the values $s_r$ into either $A_r$ or $B_r$), and these are exactly the operators whose matrix entres you have denoted as $a_{kl}^r$ and $b_{mn}^r$ respectively. Unfortunately, this collection of operators $A_r$ and $B_r$ **cannot** be the desired operators in your Theorem since they are not operators of the correct form. Namely, the operators $A_r$ and $B_r$ in the decomposition in (1) are in $A_r\in\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X})$ and $B_r\in\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{Y})$. But the operators you are looking for in your theorem are $A_r,B_r\in\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$. This is therefore not the correct singular value decomposition needed to prove the Theorem.

The "correct" way to prove the Theorem is simply to use the Choi-Jamiolkowski representation of the mapping, which is the operator $J(\Phi)\in\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{Y}\otimes\mathcal{X})$ defined as
$$
J(\Phi) = \sum_{kl}\Phi(E_{k,l})\otimes E_{k,l}.
$$
The desired operators $\{A_r: r\in\Sigma\}\subset\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ and $\{B_r: r\in\Sigma\}\subset\operatorname{L}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ now come from the singular value decomposition of $J(\Phi)$, where
$$
J(\Phi) = \sum_r \operatorname{vec}(A_r)\operatorname{vec}(B_r^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathsf{T}})^*.
$$